# Flattening mongoDB schema

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have an existing deeply nested mongoDB schema that I must flatten as I have a complex query that cannot be efficiently made with the current structure. Here is the MWE of the schema:

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "details" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2cc"),
                "a" : [
                    {
                        "unit" : "08",
                        "size" : "5",
                        "pos" : "Far",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2d0")
                    }
                ],
                "b" : [
                    {
                        "unit" : "08",
                        "size" : "5",
                        "pos" : "Far",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2cd")
                    }
                ],
                "c" : [
                    {
                        "unit" : "08",
                        "size" : "3",
                        "pos" : "Far",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2ce")
                    }
                ],
                "d" : [
                    {
                        "unit" : "08",
                        "size" : "5",
                        "pos" : "Far",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2cf")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
```

I want to flatten out the schema. The desired result is this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
"tests" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d2"),
            "aUnit" : "08",
            "aSize" : "5",
            "aPos" : "Far",
            "bPos" : "Far",
            "bSize" : "5",
            "bUnit" : "08",
            "cPos" : "Far",
            "cSize" : "3",
            "cUnit" : "08",
            "dPos" : "Far",
            "dSize" : "5",
            "dUnit" : "08"
                }
            ]
```

I'm willing to do each entry type, one at a time, and I thought I had a method to do so but it is not working. Here is what I tried:

```
db.test.find({"tests.$.details.a.unit":{$exists:true}}).forEach(function(doc) {      
    doc.tests = {aUnit:tests.details.a.unit};
    delete tests.details.a.unit;
    db.test.save(doc);
    });
```

However, this changes nothing. How can I improve my query in order to flatten my schema?

EDITED: I realized that the MWE had a minor error as compared to the one I intended to use it on. I was closing each entry. For example, `"a" : [{ ... }],` was incorrectly written as `{"a" : [{ ... }]},`. However, it is now updated.

Comment: Have you tried the `$project` `$group` and `$unwind` functions that are part of the aggregation framework?

Comment: Are you trying to "update" the data to your new form or are you trying to return a result that looks like your new form solely as a query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### New Response

**Print the data**

```
db.test.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.details = doc.details.map( detail => {
    Object.keys(detail).filter( k => k !== "_id" ).forEach( k => {
      detail[k].forEach( item => {
        Object.keys(item).filter(i => i !== "_id" ).forEach( inner => {
          detail[k + inner.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inner.substr(1)]
            = item[inner];
        })
      });
      delete detail[k];
    });
    return detail;
  });
  printjson(doc);
});
```

**Update the data**

```
db.test.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.details = doc.details.map( detail => {
    Object.keys(detail).filter( k => k !== "_id" ).forEach( k => {
      detail[k].forEach( item => {
        Object.keys(item).filter(i => i !== "_id" ).forEach( inner => {
          detail[k + inner.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inner.substr(1)]
            = item[inner];
        })
      });
      delete detail[k];
    });
    return detail;
  });

  ops = [
    ...ops,
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$set": { "doc.details": doc.details } }
    }}
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.test.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.test.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

**Output Form**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "details" : [
        {
          "_id" : ObjectId("58e55f0f68afb6085ec3a2cc"),
          "aUnit" : "08",
          "aSize" : "5",
          "aPos" : "Far",
          "bUnit" : "08",
          "bSize" : "5",
          "bPos" : "Far",
          "cUnit" : "08",
          "cSize" : "3",
          "cPos" : "Far",
          "dUnit" : "08",
          "dSize" : "5",
          "dPos" : "Far"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

### Original Data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "tests" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d2"),
        "details" : [
          {
            "a" : [
              {
                "unit" : "08",
                "size" : "5",
                "pos" : "Far",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d6")
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "b" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Drive Side Far",
                "size" : "5",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d3")
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "c" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Far",
                "size" : "3",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d4")
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "d" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Far",
                "size" : "5",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d5")
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

---

### Original Answer

If you are trying "update" your data, then it's a lot more involved than what you are trying. You have several arrays and you need to actually "traverse" the array elements rather than trying to access them directly.

Here's just a sample to "print out" the "flattened" data:

```
db.test.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.tests = doc.tests.map( test => {
    test.details.forEach( detail => {
      Object.keys(detail).forEach( key => {
        detail[key].forEach( item => {
          Object.keys(item).forEach( inner => {
            if ( inner !== '_id' ) {
              test[key + inner.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inner.substr(1)]
                = item[inner];
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
    delete test.details;
    return test;
  });
  printjson(doc);
})
```

Which I believe gives the structure you are looking for:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "tests" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d2"),
            "aUnit" : "08",
            "aSize" : "5",
            "aPos" : "Far",
            "bPos" : "Drive Side Far",
            "bSize" : "5",
            "bUnit" : "08",
            "cPos" : "Far",
            "cSize" : "3",
            "cUnit" : "08",
            "dPos" : "Far",
            "dSize" : "5",
            "dUnit" : "08"
        }
    ]

}
```

Now I'm not taking into account any possibility that inside your `"details"` array the documents with keys like `"a"` etc could maybe appear multiple times. So I am just considering that there is only ever 1 document inside there which has a an `"a"` or a `"b"` etc, and the last found value matching that key is always assigned when adding the new keys to the top level of the `"details"` documents.

If you're actual case varies, then you would need to modify various `.forEach()` loops inside there to also use the "index" as a parameter and include that index value as part of the key name. i.e:

```
"a0Unit": "08",
"a0Size": "05",
"a1Unit": "09",
"a1Size": "06"
```

But that is a detail you will have to work out if necessary since this would differ from how the data is presented in the question.

If however this is a perfect fit for what you want to update to, then simply run the loop with [`.bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) statements executing at regular intervals:

```
let ops = [];

db.test.find().forEach(doc => {
  doc.tests = doc.tests.map( test => {
    test.details.forEach( detail => {
      Object.keys(detail).forEach( key => {
        detail[key].forEach( item => {
          Object.keys(item).forEach( inner => {
            if ( inner !== '_id' ) {
              test[key + inner.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inner.substr(1)]
                = item[inner];
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
    delete test.details;
    return test;
  });

  ops = [
    ...ops,
    { "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": doc._id },
      "update": { "$set": { "tests": doc.tests } }
    }}
  ];

  if ( ops.length >= 500 ) {
    db.test.bulkWrite(ops);
    ops = [];
  }
});

if ( ops.length > 0 ) {
  db.test.bulkWrite(ops);
  ops = [];
}
```

---

It also appears from the `_id` fields present in each array member document that you are using mongoose. So whatever you do, do not try and run the code using mongoose itself. It's a "one off" bulk update of your data and should be run directly from the shell. Then of course you will need to modify your schema to suit the new structure.

But this is why you should run through your data in the shell with the `printjson()` method first.

Comment: I tried using this, however I'm getting a syntax error that is preventing me from testing it. I am running it in the shell. `SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):3:8`

Comment: @black_sheep07 Oops. Think I got a little overzealous in deleting parts. First listing that just prints should have worked perfectly though, and just fixed the update listing with the missing lines. And I just pasted the listing directly into my shell and updated the same document you supplied as shown,

Comment: Thank you. What if the name of the new thing were comprised of words, not just a letter (but still only occurring once)? For example, instead of `a` turning into `aUnit` and `b` turning into `bUnit`, I have `apple` becoming `appleUnit` and `banana` turning into `bananaUnit`?

Comment: @black_sheep07 The listing here does not care about that. It's just going to take whatever is in the key and use it. Like I said, we can only respond to what is in your question, and you were advised to use the "print" form before committing to other updates and the possibility that your actual structure may require alterations to the listing. It still should be a good base to go on, but as long as the documents follow the same document and array structure of nesting, it should work without alteration.

Comment: I am getting a failure when I try to run the code. `TypeError: detail[key].forEach is not a function`. Any reason why?

Comment: I realized that the MWE had a minor error as compared to the one I intended to use it on. I was closing each entry. For example, `"a" : [{ ... }],` was incorrectly written as `{"a" : [{ ... }]},`. However, it is now updated.

Comment: @black_sheep07 You should not have altered your question and it really is a significant change that voids responses already given, In future your correct action should be to accept the answer that answers the question **As Orginally Asked**. Such a change should be dealt with then by [Asking a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This time **only**, I have given an amended response to the  new data presented. There will be **no more** alterations. The answer supplied is to the state of data **"as is"** in the question.

Comment: My apologies. I made an additional error with this question, but all your answers have worked for the existing MWE's. However, I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44358595/flattening-very-deeply-nested-mongodb-data

Comment: @RagyIsaac If you have a new question then you can [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This is about traversing a particular data structure and moving it to differently named keys. Like all data traversal, the process is different every time.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{$unwind:"$tests"},
    {$unwind:"$tests.details"},
    {$unwind:"$tests.details.a"},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        "tests": {"$push":{
            "aPos":"$tests.details.a.pos",
            "aSize":"$tests.details.a.size",
            "aUnit":"$tests.details.a.unit"
        }}}},
    ])
```

produces:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"), "tests" : [ { "aPos" : "Far", "aSize" : "5", "aUnit" : "08" } ] }
```

The above only yielded one set of field:value pairs; doing multiple $unwind at the same level did not work:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{$unwind:"$tests"},
    {$unwind:"$tests.details"},
    {$unwind:"$tests.details.a"},
    {$unwind:"$tests.details.b"},
    {$group:{
        _id:"$_id",
        "tests": {"$push":{
            "aPos":"$tests.details.a.pos",
            "aSize":"$tests.details.a.size",
            "aUnit":"$tests.details.a.unit",
            "bPos":"$tests.details.b.pos",
            "bSize":"$tests.details.b.size",
            "bUnit":"$tests.details.b.unit"
        }}}},
    ])  //does not run
```

Therefore, there needs to be another aggregation stage of [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) to carry out similar steps for details.b, details.c and details.d.

Comment: Though you didn't attempt to use it, `$facet` is completely the wrong thing to reference here, and mainly since it's function and output are **always** a "single document", so a definite BSON limit breaker. The problem the attempt is of course you need to use "specific paths", and this may not be consistent with all documents. It's possible to do an aggregation to the desired result, but it would "flexibly" require use of `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` in order to rename the keys. It's also really unwieldy. Besides the question mentions "update". Much simpler to client side code.