# Flattening Very Deeply Nested mongoDB Data

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have an existing very deeply nested mongoDB schema that I must flatten as I have a complex query that cannot be efficiently made with the current structure. I have asked this question before, but this is more detailed. Here is the MWE of the schema:

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
    "thing1": "a thing",
    "thing2": "another thing",
    "otherSchema": [
        {
        "z": "123456",
        "y": "987654"
        }
        ],
    "tests" : [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d2"),
        "details" : [
            {
            "a" : [
              {
                "unit" : "08",
                "size" : "5",
                "pos" : "Far",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d6")
              }
            ],
            "b" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Drive Side Far",
                "size" : "5",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d3")
              }
            ],
            "c" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Far",
                "size" : "3",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d4")
              }
            ],
          "d" : [
              {
                "pos" : "Far",
                "size" : "5",
                "unit" : "08",
                "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d5")
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

My desired output is:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58e574a768afb6085ec3a388"),
"thing1": "a thing",
"thing2": "another thing",
"otherSchema": [
    "z": "123456",
    "y": "987654"
    ],
"tests" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58e542fb68afb6085ec3a1d2"),
        "aUnit" : "08",
        "aSize" : "5",
        "aPos" : "Far",
        "bPos" : "Far",
        "bSize" : "5",
        "bUnit" : "08",
        "cPos" : "Far",
        "cSize" : "3",
        "cUnit" : "08",
        "dPos" : "Far",
        "dSize" : "5",
        "dUnit" : "08"
            }
        ]
```

In [this previously asked/answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273798/flattening-mongodb-schema), it fulfills the MWE in that question but fails when more info is added, as is added above. However, a derivation of that answer would be very helpful. I do want to replace the existing data.

Can you please explain the steps taken so I can apply this to a larger database?

Comment: There is no change here from how the question was originally asked in the linked duplicate. The only change is the addition "other_schema" property for which **A)** Does not actually get touched by the process you were advised of. **B)** Has an invalid output format since you specify "keys" directly inside an array. As is the original answer provides  the correct and valid output even with the additional key. If you believe otherwise, then please make sure to include a valid output format and a clear statement of what you want to achieve that is different.

Comment: The hold is placed to avoid "copy & paste" answers, which would be highly likely at this present time. I will also state that the eventual goal of asking questions here should be to "learn", rather than ask for someone to code solutions for you. There should have been more than enough information and example provided in answer to your previous question for you to at least attempt to solve any "difference" yourself. And again, if this applies to a **real** live data, then show what you actually have, as opposed to an approximate representation.